# Work Flow / Design

Tags: c#

I am student working on College Management Software,

In my Finance Module, before any fee collection from the student there should be demand, So, once the demand generated the fee collection can be done in

1. Indian rupees
2. Dollars Or any other currency type.

but by native is to collect in INDIAN Rupees,

My Problem,

I can collect indian rupees, but for dollars, if i collect it , i don't know the value of the dollars in Indian rupees during collection. The cashier will put the money in bank on next day, so there may be chances of dollars value varies.

How to implement this functionality in my project. Can any body guide me to accomplish the task

I am using .Net 1.1,Oracle 9i database.

Thanks,
Sunil

Comment: I think this is probably an accounting question not a programming question since the implementation will depend on the accounting rules (e.g. is there a separate account for funds not yet deposited?, etc.).

Comment: In clear you are asking the community, to "think" your assignment for you. "Thinking" the design is part of your software engineering education. If you are not able to solve that for yourself, you'd better leave engineering and go for something less demanding.

Comment: Thanks - Mika Jacobi First its heart me but later U made me to think, i done with project, and it was implemented successfully...

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain a list of currency rates by sync'ing to some valid resource(for instance a web). For this you will need:

**Windows Service**

To maintain the latest currency rates, you can create a windows service that would *sync* your database with online rates. For instance, there are alot of web sites that provides latest currency rates in form of xml, or web services, etc.

**Web Service:**

You can come up with a web service that would ask for the `InputCurrencyType`, `InputAmount`, `OutputCurrencyType` and returns the converted amount. For instance:

```
decimal dINR = YourCurrencyConversionWebService.ConvertCurrency("USD", "2000", "INR");
```

Every time a user deposits foreign currency, you can call the your `Currency Conversion` web service and save the returned local currency amount in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Well , you can acheive this by windows workflow BUT you are not using any higher version of .net and why are you not using higher version.

BUT as a starting point

1- Maintain two set of database tables one may be called Fee_Transcation_Request and Second will be called suppose Fee_Transaction_Persisted.

2- Whenever you are doing any transaction related to fee , it must be stored in the _Request table as because it is not commited yet.

3- Let the cahsier log into the application , ther must be a work quequ (Can be a grid control)of open request form the _Request table.

4- Cashier will pick the request , do some magic on the request and submit , when cashier is submitting this request , you can persist the fee details in the actual _Persisted table.

this is just starting logic